# Tell how an argument was received by a function?

Tags: python, debugging, cpython

I would like to know if the following introspection is possible in cpython:

```
>>> def potato(x=69):
...     if x == 69 and ???:
...         print '69 was taken from argument defaults'
...     if x == 69 and ???:
...         print '69 was passed as positional arg'
...     if x == 69 and ???:
...         print '69 was passed as kwarg'
...
>>> potato()
69 was taken from argument defaults
>>> potato(69)
69 was passed as positional arg
>>> potato(x=69)
69 was passed as kwarg
```

I'm interested in both python2 and python3 answers, if they are different.

Any kind of blackmagic involving `inspect`, `traceback`, `pdb`, `sys._getframe` etc is permissable here.  Of course, modifying the argspec of the function is not allowed.

Comment: You'd have to analyse the source code of the calling frame. Which could be using `potato(*args)` or `potato(**kwargs)`, at which point you need to analyse what is *in* `args` or `kwargs`, etc. This gets complicated *fast*.

Comment: The calling frame could also have stored `potato` under a *different* name, or in a list. A decorator might be involved, or `exec` or `eval()`. Or the function was invoked as a callback through a C extension. *shudder*. The possibilities are endless here.

Comment: Just hit `u` in `pdb` to step up a frame in the stack and look at what code was executed there. You as a human can far more easily check what happened there and what was being passed to `potato`.

Comment: Do you have a use case in mind for *why* you would want this level of discrimination, or are you just curious? The first case could be handled by letting `x=None` by default, then using `if x is None: x = 69`

Comment: For a debugger .. basically the automated equivalent of the "hit u in pdb to step up a frame" method that Martijn mentions

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like *inspect* can provide this information directly although frames have a string called *code_context* which gives you the source line at which the function was called. The problem is that one would have to rewrite a small parser to make sense of it.

Here is a simpler solution based on a wrapper around the function you want to examine. It doesn't change the arg spec and the arg validation isn't changed either :

```
import inspect

def track_args(func):
    def tracker(*args, **kwargs):
        r = func(*args, **kwargs)
        for arg_num,arg_name in enumerate(inspect.getargspec(func)[0]):
            if arg_name in kwargs:
                print "%s was provided as keyword arg" % arg_name
            elif arg_num < len(args):
                print "%s was provided as positional arg" % arg_name
            else:
                print "%s was provided by default value" % arg_name
        return r
    return tracker

@track_args
def f(a, b, c=30):
    print "I'm f()"

f(20, b=10)
f(20)
```

Result with valid arguments:

```
I'm f()
a was provided as positional arg
b was provided as keyword arg
c was provided by default value
```

Result with invalid arguments:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    f(20)
  File "test.py", line 5, in tracker
    r = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: f() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Using a decorator is kind of cheating / dodging the real question.  Behind the scenes with the @ syntax, you are rebinding the name `f` to `track_args(f)`.   But +1 anyway for you  :)